# XPath to extract all text between two 'p' elements scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape a database using Scrapy and Splash, which requires login so unfortunately, I am unable to share the full website. The database contains a list of companies showing their name and a short description.

I am struggling to find an XPath expression that would yield all the text between the two 'p' tags as shown:

```
<p class="pre-wrap ng-binding"
ng-bind-html="object._source.startup.general_information.project_public_description"
ng-click="listView.showDetail(object)" role="button" tabindex="0">
  <div>With the vision of providing creative sustainable solutions for global food crisis,
    AquiNovo develops innovative, non-GMO, non-hormonal, peptide-based feed additives,
    addressing the ever-growing demand for fish protein. Company’s additives improve both growth
    performance and feed utilization, enabling the <strong><em>growth of more fish with less
            feed</em></strong>. A unique peptide production system, enables large commercial
    scale production at significant lower cost and carbon footprint. Growing more fish with less
    feed also promote several SDG’s including the reduction of pressure on fish population in
    the sea, providing food security and reducing hunger and poverty, climate change and
    responsible production.&nbsp;</div>
</p>
```

All the company descriptions are in the same format (between two 'p' elements), but as shown in the HTML, there are `<strong><em>` elements as well. I would like to ask for help to find a way to create an XPath that would get all text including the ones in the `<strong><em>` element as one single text block (that would be one description, when viewed on the website there is no separation in the text.

I tried the following but that only gets the part before the element `//p[@class='pre-wrap ng-binding']//div//text()`

I used the following code:

```
'the descript': ''.join(startup.xpath('//div//text()').getall()),
```

Comment: Please provide the Entire HTML of that page

Comment: The computed text value of `//p[@class='pre-wrap ng-binding']` should be all you need.  Select that element and ask for it's value. You could also do that for the `div`.

Comment: Show the code that you are using to apply the XPath. Are you using `.xpath().get()` or `.xpath.getAll()`?

Comment: @Prophet, I tried to include it but when I view the page source it does not contain the HTML that I have added here, if you have a way to do it please let me know

Comment: @MadsHansen I was using .xpath().get() but after the answer below I changed it to getAll()

Answer (score 1):

```py
scrapy shell

In [1]: html = """<html>
   ...: <body>
   ...: <p class="pre-wrap ng-binding"
   ...: ng-bind-html="object._source.startup.general_information.project_public_description"
   ...: ng-click="listView.showDetail(object)" role="button" tabindex="0">
   ...:   <div>With the vision of providing creative sustainable solutions for global food crisis,
   ...:     AquiNovo develops innovative, non-GMO, non-hormonal, peptide-based feed additives,
   ...:     addressing the ever-growing demand for fish protein. Company’s additives improve both growth
   ...:     performance and feed utilization, enabling the <strong><em>growth of more fish with less
   ...:             feed</em></strong>. A unique peptide production system, enables large commercial
   ...:     scale production at significant lower cost and carbon footprint. Growing more fish with less
   ...:     feed also promote several SDG’s including the reduction of pressure on fish population in
   ...:     the sea, providing food security and reducing hunger and poverty, climate change and
   ...:     responsible production.&nbsp;</div>
   ...: </p>
   ...: </body>
   ...: </html>"""

In [2]: selector = scrapy.Selector(text=html)

In [3]: ''.join(selector.xpath('//div//text()').getall())
Out[3]: 'With the vision of providing creative sustainable solutions for global food crisis,\n    AquiNovo develops innovative, non-GMO, non-hormonal, peptide-based feed additives,\n    addressing the ever-growing demand for fish protein. Company’s additives improve both growth\n    performance and feed utilization, enabling the growth of more fish with less\n            feed. A unique peptide production system, enables large commercial\n    scale production at significant lower cost and carbon footprint. Growing more fish with less\n    feed also promote several SDG’s including the reduction of pressure on fish population in\n    the sea, providing food security and reducing hunger and poverty, climate change and\n    responsible production.\xa0'
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped as I finally got some text from the description section. The problem is that this grabbed way too much text not only the text within the HTML that I posted. Would you happen to know why //p//text() does not get any text only ' '?

Comment: To fix your problem either add the parent of the div tag to the xpath selector, or add the position of the div in the html. About //p//text(), acording the the HTML standard `div` cant be inside of `p`, so if you type `selector.xpath('//p').get()` you'll see that there's a `</p>` BEFORE the `div` tag hence you actually have: `<p...>\n</p><div>...</div>` (at least that's my theory).

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not work, even when I tried your suggestions.

Comment: @BerciVagyok If you share to url I could help more.

Comment: I am unfortunately unable to provide it as it requires login credentials which I cannot provide :/ Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: @BerciVagyok can you add the source of this specific page that you want?

Comment: When clicking view source the relevant info is not there, the best way I found is to take a screenshot, but I have gotten negative feedback for posting a screenshot in the question, would you know a better way of sharing it, maybe a way I could send it to you?

Comment: Type `print(response.body)` in the function that handles the page you want to scrape.